# Updating row in Access DB using command object is not working

Tags: c#, command

Got stuck with simple task of updating a row in access database using command object from my windows forms app. I'm able to insert record but somehow not able to update the record:

```
 private void openDB()
        {
            DBPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\myDB.mdb";
            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + DBPath);
            conn.Open();
        }

 private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string insertString;
            openDB();
            string updateString;
            updateString = "Update Address SET Name='"+ txtName.Text.Trim() +  "', IsActive='" + chkAddressActive.Checked +"' where MemberID="+txtMemberID.Text.Trim();
            //MessageBox.Show(updateString);
            using (OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(updateString, conn))
            {
                updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully", "Transaction", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                dgView.Enabled = true;
                ReloadDataForSelectedMember();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the query string that gets generated

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like this as *Name* is a reserved word:

```
updateString = "Update Address SET [Name] = '" + txtName.Text.Trim() + "', IsActive = " + chkAddressActive.Checked.ToString() + " Where MemberID = " + txtMemberID.Text.Trim();
```